# What's the best way to install a very minimal Windows 10 as a Virtual Machine to run photoshop in?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, adobe-photoshop

I need to use the Creative Cloud for Photoshop, Illustrator, etc for work so I'd like to install a very minimal windows 10, in Ubuntu VirtualBox, so I can run just what's necessary so Photoshop can run as fast as possible.

Note: This question was asked in Ask Ubuntu and was Closed as being off-topic. I was told that it should be asked here but I'm not sure that it is on-topic here either. What do Windows guys know about running VBox in Ubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214611/whats-the-best-way-to-install-a-very-minimal-windows-10-as-a-virtual-machine-to#comment2041875_1214611

Comment: If you want a minimal installation you have to create the Windows installation image yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound: Would that make Windows run faster? How to start creating this image?

Comment: If you have never created your own Windows installation image, you realistically will not have the knowledge set, to create a minimal Windows configuration.  There are images created by other Windows users that might fit your requirements.  However, asking for a "minimal Windows installation", is extremely broad description and/or requirement.  It's not clear the reason a stock Windows image will not work.

Comment: @Ramhound: The only need for a minimal Windows install would be if it made Photoshop run faster in Windows. This Windows install would be running in VBox in Ubuntu. Do you know of any way to speed that up besides tweaking Photoshop or VBox or hardware? I have never been able to make Windows run faster than a fresh install, no secret fast button.

Comment: Make sure your host machine has an SSD drive, and maybe consider VMware Workstation instead of Virtual Box. I have that host setup here and guests work very well and certainly fast enough.

Comment: There might be a work-around running it on ubuntu: https://community.adobe.com/t5/get-started/adobe-cc-on-ubuntu-linux/td-p/9834114?page=1

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.ntlite.com/discussions/#/discussion/1364/tutorial-for-creating-a-700-mb-windows-10-iso-and-install-in-a-vm

Comment: Thank you fir the comments, to clairify, I am not talking about Hardware or VBox or Ubuntu Tweaks, Just Tweaks to the Windows OS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### The best way to install Windows 10 as a Virtual Machine to run Photoshop in Ubuntu.

There is not a lot that you can do to Windows to make it run faster in VBox except to disable background applications and virus protection, (if you are brave).

There are things that you can do to your hardware, VirtualBox and Ubuntu to make Photoshop in a Windows guest run faster.

**Hardware:**

- Add RAM
- Add a fast SSD dedicated to Ubuntu.
- Add a faster CPU
- Add a better GPU
- Ensure Intel VT-x or AMD-V Is Enabled

**Ubuntu**

- Keep Ubuntu updated
- Use lightweight desktop alternatives
- Monitor startup apps
- Do not add unnecessary software
- Get rid of heavy startup applications
- Increase Swap Space if you can not afford RAM
- Enable Proprietary Drivers
- Clean out old files
- Reduce the default grub load time
- Install preload to speed up application load time

**VirtualBox:**

- Create your machine using a fixed size disk
- Allocate more memory
- Install Guest Additions
- Install Extension Packs
- Enabling copy paste
- Increase display memory
- Allocate more CPUs
- Ensure Intel VT-x or AMD-V Is Enabled
- Enable 2D / 3D Acceleration
- Suspend Instead of Shutting Down
- use the Intel PRO/1000 network drivers if using a network
- Some people report VirtualBox being faster, while others report VMware being faster

**Photoshop**

Set performance-related preferences

- Adjust the memory allocated to Photoshop
- Adjust cache levels
- Limit history states
- Set graphics processor (GPU) settings

Fine-tune Photoshop features for performance

- Work within file-size limitations
- Close unnecessary document windows
- Reduce patterns and brush tips in presets
- Minimize or turn off panel preview thumbnails
- Change file compatibility options
- Work in 8-bit image mode
- Turn off WYSIWYG font preview
- Reduce image resolution
- Purge the clipboard
- Use the Filter Gallery
- Drag between files rather than copy and paste
- Use layers wisely
- Save TIFF files without layers
- Don’t export the clipboard
- Disable the Libraries panel
- Disable Device Preview
- Disable Generator
- Disable Rulers
- Disable Font Preview
- Restart the Creative Cloud desktop app
- Use A Scratch Disk
- Use 64-bit Architecture